# Image path issue in yii2

Tags: php, url, yii2

I have frontend,backend and API's in my yii2 project.I have remove front/web from url.I follow following post for that.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/
But my entire images getting not found error in backend and frontend.I am facing problem to give path.I have tried following code
In params-local.php

```
   Yii ::setAlias('@source', 'http://example.com');
```

In Frontend/index.php

```
<body style="background-image:url(.<?Yii ::getAlias('@source') ?>.'/images/media-bg.jpg');background-attachment:fixed;">
```

Still getting Error (#2) .Please help

Comment: first you set alias and than you get alias wherever u need. so this <?Yii ::setAlias('@source') ?> will be <?Yii ::getAlias('@source') ?>

Comment: Please specify the error you are getting

Comment: I am getting Error(#2) Internal server error

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax error in this line:

```
<?Yii ::getAlias('@source') ?>
```

Replace with:

```
<?= Yii ::getAlias('@source') ?>
```

Set Alias(common/config/bootstrap.php):

```
Yii::setAlias('@root', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
```

Get Alias:

```
Yii ::getAlias('@root');
```

Getting Uploaded image from project root directory

```
<img src="<?= Yii ::getAlias('@root').'uploads/images/cool.png';?> ">
```