# Show an image from frontend in backend in html img tag

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-url-manager

I want show an image in backend, that uploaded at a directory in frontend/web/uploads

this is my backend config:

```
'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'shop/frontend/web',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
```

this is my Html img tag in view file

```
Html::img(\Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->baseUrl.'/' .$pathImg, ['class' => 'file-preview-image']);
```

but it return this url:

```
http://localhost/shop/backend/web/product/shop/frontend/web/uploads/My Image.jpg
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: show me `$pathimg` code?

Comment: uploads/My Image.jpg

Comment: can you use a alias for showing image?

Comment: try my solution, let me know about any issue!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `shope` from  `'baseUrl' => 'shop/frontend/web'`, if doesn't work then try below solution, base url should look like this: `'baseUrl' => 'frontend/web/',`

Try this!

Backend config:

```
'components' => [
        //can name it whatever you want as it is custom
        'urlManagerFrontend' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
                'baseUrl' => 'frontend/web/',
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
],
```

Frontend config(optional)

```
'components' => [
        'urlManagerBackend' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
                'baseUrl' => 'backend/web/',
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
],
```

And in img tag:

```
Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->baseUrl.'/uploads/My Image.jpg');
```

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202972/image-path-issue-in-yii2/37207734#37207734)

Comment: what is url of image now?

Comment: I checked your solution and the url didn't change, then i checked the solution in the above link it return c:\xampp\htdocs\shop/uploads/My Image.jpg

Comment: first try my given solution in answer

Comment: I checked it, it didn't work, there was no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112565/discussion-between-muhammad-shahzad-and-amin-shafiee).